# Как инициализировать класс, с помощью объекта

Tags: java

Заранее прошу прощение, если сформулировал вопрос немного некорректно

```
Vana result = new Vana("Ravak", 1, 2, 3);
Vana instance = new Vana("Ravak", new Rozmer(1, 2, 3));
```

Нужно сделать конструкторы, которые бы инициализировали клаcc vana(это тест)

```
    Vana(String ravak, double delka, double sirka, double vyska){
        super(delka,sirka,vyska);
        this.ravak=ravak;
    }

    public Vana(String ravak, Rozmer rozmer) {
        super(rozmer);
        this.ravak=ravak;
    }
```

Так выглядит код, который я написал, но только второй инициализатор, где должен проходить объект, выдает ошибку. Я понимаю, что вариант однозначно неправильный, но как взять из него информацию, которую задали в начале?

```
public Rozmer(final double delka, final double sirka, final double vyska) throws MojeException {
        if (!check(delka) || !check(sirka) || !check(vyska)) throw new MojeException("Chyba");
        this.delka = Math.round(delka*TO_CM);
        this.sirka = Math.round(sirka*TO_CM);
        this.vyska = Math.round(vyska*TO_CM);
    }
```

Это конструктор наследственного класса, на который я ссылаюсь.
Работать можно только с кодом, где конструкторы

Comment: От какого класса порождён класс `Ravak`?  Есть ли в этом классе конструктор, принимающий аргумент `Rozmer`?

Comment: Ravak это название переменной, которая объявлена в классе, с конструкторами как String, но она тут, как мне кажется не играет роли. ``` Vana instance = new Vana("Ravak", new Rozmer(1, 2, 3)); ``` Мне нужно сделать конструктор для этого класса. Все 3 года принадлежать разным классам, первый это тест VanaTest, второй класс - Vana, созданный для выполнения тестов из этого класса и он extends Rozmer, 3 код - это конструктор этого класса. Суть в том, что я не знаю, Как сделать конструктор, где был бы объект, и ссылался super на констурктор класса rozmer
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Как то я загнул с объяснением, если коротко и ясно, нужен конструктор для ` Vana instance = new Vana("Ravak", new Rozmer(1, 2, 3)); `, чтобы его параметру наследствовали класса Rozmer, типа как в первом варианте.

Answer (score 0):

Итак:

- в классе `Rozmer` определён только один конструктор, принимающий все три размера,
- в классе `Vana`, унаследованном от `Rozmer`, есть работающий конструктор:

```java
class Vana extends Rozmer {
    Vana (String ravak, double delka, double sirka, double vyska) {
        super(delka, sirka, vyska);
        this.ravak = ravak;
    }
}
```

Тогда конструктор класса `Vana`, принимающий аргумент `Rozmer`, можно определить так:

```java
// class Vana
    public Vana (String ravak, Rozmer rozmer) {
        this(ravak, rozmer.delka, rozmer.sirka, rozmer.vyska);
    }
```